# Node.js server with express, whats the best way to require files and memory

Tags: javascript, node.js

So for convenience and readability it is always a good idea to declare your variables up top ie;

However I was wondering how js handles requiring files. Is it all loaded at declaration or is it loaded at time of execution? is there a meaningful difference ( if only one "FILE" is ever required to run program )  between declaration up top

```
var File1 = require('../api/file1.js');
var File2 = require('../api/file2.js');
var File3 = require('../api/file3.js'); 
var File4 = require('../api/file3.js');
var ManyOtherRequiredFiles = require('..');

if(1){
  var file = new File1();
  file.run()
}else if(2){
  var file = new File2();
  file.run()
}else if(3){
  var file = new File3();
  file.run()
}else{
  var file = new File4();
  file.run()
}
```

or not declaring up top but declaring when needed:

```
var ManyOtherRequiredFiles = require('..');

if(1){
  var File = require('../api/file1.js');
  var file = new File();
  file.run()
}else if(2){
  var File = require('../api/file2.js');
  var file = new File();
  file.run()
}else if(3){
  var File = require('../api/file3.js');
  var file = new File();
  file.run()
}else{
  var File = require('../api/file4.js');
  var file = new File();
  file.run()
}
```

Is there a meaningful difference on memory between these two options?; if so, is requiring files when needed the best way to go about things?

if not, Is declaring and creating new instances up top any different or worse?

```
var File1 = require('../api/file1.js');
var file1 = new File1();
```

or

```
var file1 = new require('../api/file1.js')();
```

etc.;

Comment: Intuition says requiring only when needed will be more efficient.

Comment: js could be pretty smart; if the gain is small readability would be more important

Comment: I don't think you lose much readability here anyways.

Comment: If it's not obvious.... The code above is not the actual code I'm writing

Comment: It depends on what's done during requiring the module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

modules are loaded as soon as you call the `require` function.

Each module loaded is cached using the expanded path of the file as the cache key.

if you load the same file 5 times, it only gets loaded once because the cache key will be the same - even if you specify different paths, such as "../file.js" or "../../foo/file.js" - as long as both of these paths point to the same file, relative to wherever you made the `require` call, it will re-use the already loaded module.

> Is there a meaningful difference on memory between these two options?;

slightly, but only until you end up loading the files.

the amount of memory used by loading another module into memory is negligible. it's the use of code within that module that adds up fast.

for example, you could have a very tiny file with only 3 or 4 lines of code... but that code may loop 1billion+ times, using a large chunk of memory each iteration.

your concern should not be so much memory usage by loading modules, but memory usage by the code you wrote.

additionally, the idea of lazy loading modules would affect performance more than memory.

the `require` call is relatively expensive, since it must happen synchronously. synchronous file access will block *everything* in your app until the file is loaded.

because of this, and the small footprint of memory for loading a module, it's best to load all modules at the beginning of the app startup cycle. just let the `require` calls be at the top of your file and be done with it.

> if not, Is declaring and creating new instances up top any different or worse?

this makes little to no difference, if you're only requiring the file once in a given module

Comment: Hey thanks! Do you know where I learn and read more about it?

Comment: honestly don't remember how / where i learned this stuff. i've read bits and pieces of it around the web, in books and from talking to different people